# Python Selenium: ElementNotInteractableException error on click()

Tags: python, selenium

I run the script and it gives me one of two errors:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <a class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);"> could not be scrolled into view
```

or

```
Element not found error
```

Right now this is the error it's giving. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I have been trying to change the timing around to get it working right but to no avail. It will not work.

Code:

```
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



def get_page(model, sku):
    url = "https://www.footlocker.com/product/model:"+str(model)+"/sku:"+ str(sku)+"/"
    return url 

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
page=browser.get(get_page(277097,"8448001"))
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pdp_size_select_mask']").click()
link = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#size_selection_list")))
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#size_selection_list').click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#size_selection_list > a:nth-child(8)').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pdp_addtocart_button']").click()
checkout = browser.get('https://www.footlocker.com/shoppingcart/default.cfm?sku=')
checkoutbutton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#cart_checkout_button').click()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website automatically opens the size_selection_list div, so you don't need to click on it. But you do need to wait for the particular list element that you want to select. This code worked for me on this site a couple of times consistently.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def get_page(model, sku):
    url = "https://www.footlocker.com/product/model:"+str(model)+"/sku:"+ str(sku)+"/"
    return url

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
page=browser.get(get_page(277097,"8448001"))
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pdp_size_select_mask']").click()
shoesize = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.grid_size:nth-child(8)')))
shoesize.click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pdp_addtocart_button']").click()
checkout = browser.get('https://www.footlocker.com/shoppingcart/default.cfm?sku=')
checkoutbutton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#cart_checkout_button').click()
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. I wait for the element to be clickable, but I'm still getting the ElementNotInteractableException.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so: can you provide more of the stack trace for the "element not found" error? I stepped through the live Foot Locker site and didn't find the `cart_checkout_button`, though I may have made a mistake.

I'm also not sure (in your specific example) that you need to be clicking the `size_selection_list` the first time, before clicking the child, but I'm not as concerned about that. The syntax overall looks OK to me.

---

edit with the provided stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "./footlocker_price.py", line 29, in browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#size_selection_list > a:nth-child(8)').click()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 501, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response 
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element could not be scrolled into view
```

What this means is that the click on `#size_selection_list > a:nth-child(8)` is failing because it can't be interacted with directly. Some other element is in the way. [reference](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/common/exceptions.py#L167)

Due to the way the particular page you're interacting with works (which is [here](https://www.footlocker.com/product/model:277097/sku:8448001) for others reading this), I believe the size selection list is simply hidden when the page loads, and is displayed after you click on the Size button.

It seems like the `ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#size_selection_list")))` line should do what you want, though, so I'm at a little bit of a loss. If you add in a `time.sleep(5)` before you click on the size element, does it work? It's not ideal but maybe it will get you moving on to other parts of this.